# the redirected page is not being displayed in spring-mvc ajax GET request

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am redirecting a web page to another webpage on button click. But the redirected page does not open and I am getting error that `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI ['UserTest/redirect/npage']`. However, this path is valid and is defined inside my project. The npage.jsp file/page exist too inside view folder. So what can be the issue and why this page is not being reached? ***I have explored many similar question but none has worked for me. Therefore please help.***

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>User Test</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**UserTest-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.test" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/view/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**JAVA**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String redirect() {

      return "redirect:npage";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/npage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String finalPage() {

      return "npage";
   }
```

**AJAX**

```
function nopg() {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "/UserTest/redirect"
                });
            }
```

Comment: What is the request mapping for your controller having `finalPage` method?

Comment: Try `return "redirect:/npage";` as it seems from the error message `['UserTest/redirect/npage']` is trying to hit the wrong URL.

Comment: You have not a mapping for '/UserTest/redirect', you have it for '/redirect'. Change your mapping or your ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

**try to pass full path in ajax call**

```
url : "/UserTest/redirect" // here
```